# PHP regex: how to store $1, $2 in a variable

Tags: php, regex

```
preg_replace('/([a-z]+)([0-9]+)/', '$2$1', $str);
```

I want to store $1 and $2 in a variable. How can I store it in a variable?

Comment: what means OR? how will you decide which of them to store?

Answer (score 5):

Finding matches is the job of [`preg_match()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

```
preg_match('/([a-z]+)([0-9]+)/', $str, $matches);
```

> **matches**:
>       If matches is provided, then it is filled with the results of search. $matches[0] will contain the text that matched the full
>   pattern, $matches[1] will have the text that matched the first
>   captured parenthesized subpattern, and so on.

```
$full_pattern = $matches[0]
$a = $matches[1] // $1
$b = $matches[2] // $2
$c = $matches[3] // $3
$n = $matches[n] // $n
```

Comment: of course! the most efficient and easiest way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Use [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
$one; $two;

function callback($matches)
{
   global $one,$two;
   $one = $matches[0];
   $two = $matches[1];
   return $matches[1].$matches[0];
}

preg_replace_callback('/([a-z]+)([0-9]+)/', 'callback', $str);
```

### NOTE

Global is... not a good idea. I actually left that in because it is a concise, clear example of how to accomplish what you're trying to do. I would that I had never used the word, but global is there now and I don't feel right removing it. Actually, its existence saddens me deeply. You are far better off with something like this:

```
class Replacer
{
    private $matches, $pattern, $callback;

    public function __construct($pattern, $callback)
    {
        $this->pattern = $pattern;
        $this->callback = $callback;
    }

    public function getPregCallback()
    {
        return array( $this, '_callback' );
    }

    public function _callback( array $matches )
    {
        $template = $this->pattern;
        foreach( $matches as $key => $val )
        {
            if( $this->callback ) 
            {
               $matches[ $key ] = $val = $this->callback( $val );
            }
            $template = str_replace( '$' . ( $key + 1 ), $val, $template );
        }
        $this->matches = $matches;
        return $template;
    }

    public function getMatches(){ return $this->matches; }
}
```

USE

```
// does what the first example did, plus it calls strtolower on all 
// of the elements.
$r = new Replacer( '$2$1', 'strtolower' );
preg_replace_callback('/([a-z]+)([0-9]+)/', $r->getPregCallback(), $str);

list( $a, $b ) = $r->getMatches();
```

Answer (score 0):

use preg_replace with "e" ( eval flag) 
or better use
preg_replace_callback

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php

see code here  :

http://codepad.org/22Qh3wRA

```
<?php

$str = "a9";
preg_replace_callback('/([a-z]+)([0-9]+)/', "callBackFunc", $str);

function callBackFunc($matches)
{
var_dump($matches);
// here you can assign $matches elements to variables.
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [preg_replace_callback](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
preg_replace_callback('/([a-z]+)([0-9]+)/', function($m) {
    // save data
    return $m[1].$m[0];
}, $str);
```

(This uses PHP 5.3 anonymous function syntax, on older PHP just define a normal function and pass its name as the second parameter.)